# Flutter web platform check

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to find a way to see which platform (iOS or Android) my flutter web project is running on. When I use `if (Platform.isIOS) { //do something }`, I face error below:

```
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:44159/dart_sdk.js:4334:11)
at Function._operatingSystem (http://localhost:44159/dart_sdk.js:55064:17)
at Function.get operatingSystem [as operatingSystem] (http://localhost:44159/dart_sdk.js:55110:27)
at get _operatingSystem (http://localhost:44159/dart_sdk.js:55023:27)
at Function.desc.get [as _operatingSystem] (http://localhost:44159/dart_sdk.js:4819:15)
at get isIOS (http://localhost:44159/dart_sdk.js:55047:26)
at Function.desc.get [as isIOS] (http://localhost:44159/dart_sdk.js:4819:15)
at http://localhost:44159/packages/itoll/main.dart.lib.js:364:33
at wrapper (http://localhost:44159/dart_sdk.js:59904:30)
at http://localhost:44159/:70:11123
```

Is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try to do like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP is not trying to find if it's on web but in which OS it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
  //current platform is Android
} else if(defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS){
  //current platform is macOS
}...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
    
if (kIsWeb) {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData
}
```

For the next person that has the same question as Antonio/OP. (I'd comment but not enough points)