# Flutter web is giving error about Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage, flutter-web

Flutter web is giving an error about `Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem` codes are running properly on flutter android. I think the error is with my upload image method it's not working on flutter web.

```
Here is the error

    Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:5388:11)
    at Function._operatingSystem (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:61565:17)
    at Function.get operatingSystem [as operatingSystem] (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:61611:27)
    at get _operatingSystem (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:61524:27)
    at Function.desc.get [as _operatingSystem] (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:5897:17)
    at get isWindows (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:61542:26)
    at Function.desc.get [as isWindows] (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:5897:17)
    at Function._isAbsolute (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:56712:33)
    at io._File.new.get isAbsolute [as isAbsolute] (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:56708:34)
    at io._File.new.get [_absolutePath] (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:56719:26)
    at io._File.new.get absolute [as absolute] (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:58252:30)
    at firebase_storage.Reference.__.putFile (http://localhost:37805/packages/firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart.lib.js:385:27)
    at productprovider.ProductProvider.new.uploadProductImage (http://localhost:37805/packages/phataphat_web_dashboard/services/productprovider.dart.lib.js:223:93)
    at uploadProductImage.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:43060:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:43091:7)
    at productprovider.ProductProvider.new.uploadProductImage (http://localhost:37805/packages/phataphat_web_dashboard/services/productprovider.dart.lib.js:218:20)
    at http://localhost:37805/packages/phataphat_web_dashboard/pages/product/widget/addnewproduct.dart.lib.js:1342:47
    at ink_well._InkResponseState.new.[_handleTap] (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/material/icon_button.dart.lib.js:44059:31)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.invokeCallback (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.lib.js:201:18)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleTapUp (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:429:40)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.[_checkUp] (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:229:12)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handlePrimaryPointer (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart.lib.js:175:23)
    at tap.TapGestureRecognizer.new.handleEvent (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart.lib.js:454:16)
    at pointer_router.PointerRouter.new.[_dispatch] (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:94:9)
    at http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:125:26
    at LinkedMap.new.forEach (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:29167:11)
    at pointer_router.PointerRouter.new.[_dispatchEventToRoutes] (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:122:29)
    at pointer_router.PointerRouter.new.route (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart.lib.js:114:37)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handleEvent (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:397:26)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:383:24)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:5819:13)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerEventImmediately] (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:356:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handlePointerEvent (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:329:43)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_flushPointerEventQueue] (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:318:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerDataPacket] (http://localhost:37805/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:308:65)
    at Object.invoke1 (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:204155:7)
    at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.invokeOnPointerDataPacket (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:182962:15)
    at _engine.PointerBinding.__.[_onPointerData] (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:183925:49)
    at http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:184408:28
    at http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:184361:16
    at loggedHandler (http://localhost:37805/dart_sdk.js:184035:11)
```

Here are the codes

```
 Future<String> uploadProductImage(filePath, productName) async {
    File file = File(filePath);
    var timeStamp = Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

    try {
      await _storage
          .ref('ProductImage/$productName$timeStamp')
          .putFile(file);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // e.g, e.code == 'canceled'
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e.code);
      }
    }
    String downloadURL = await _storage
        .ref('ProductImage/$productName$timeStamp')
        .getDownloadURL();
    productUrl = downloadURL;
    notifyListeners();
    return downloadURL;
  }
```

Comment: @

Adie RT Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav Thanks for your precious answer but I was using the wrong package for flutter web. I was using **Image Piker** instead of  **Image Piker for web** .

Comment: @ Adie RT Edited my answer as resolved by you, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by Adie, the issue has been resolved by using [Image Piker for web](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web).

you can refer to the similar [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63704551/15774176):

> **method 1 :**
>
> ```
> import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
>
>     if (kIsWeb) {
>       //do something
>     }
> ```
>
> **method 2:**
>
> ```
> import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
>
> if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
>   //current platform is Android
> } else if(defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS){
>   //current platform is macOS
> }...
> ```

For more information you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36126) where a similar issue has been discussed.